# Mongoose Model.create and bluebird promises

Tags: mongoose, bluebird

I'm unable to use bluebird promise functions (`catch`, `spread`, `each`) with chains that start with a `Model.create()` promise. I'm currently on mongoose 4.1.0 with bluebird 2.9.34. Everything works fine if I use `.save()`

Is there a workaround for this right now?

Thanks

Comment: Mongoose's promise implementation doesn't support those utility functions, but at the top of [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-bluebird-utils) are some tips on how to wrap Mongoose model methods with Bluebird.

Comment: Thank you for the response @robertklep. Just tried the promisifyAll code at the top of that page you linked, and got "TypeError: Illegal access to a strict mode caller function." I've also tried every suggestion in this thread https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2308 - still not able to get `.catch()` working with `.create()` (once again, I note that it completely works if I use `.save()`.